# Why am I getting a "Error Retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert'"?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project properties, I have Android 2.2 and another guy on team is able to build just fine. I get the error in my themes.xml file under under res->values

```
Error Retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert'.
```

I am therefore unable to build my project. This is a proper project that I am getting from a SVN repository and import into Eclipse.

```
<!-- DA.Theme.Dialog.Alert.* defines custom theme for any alert dialogs -->
    <style name="DA.Dialog.Alert" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DA.TextView</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: It seems it is looking for Style Theme.Dialog.Alert, which is not there. Make sure it is available. If it is there, do a cleanup of your project.

Comment: I already did cleanup and that did nothing. :S

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve it? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Try increasing the min-sdk requirement in your manifest file.
For me it gave same error in the styles file **res/values14/styles.xml** at

```
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
```

After barking up different trees changing the **min-sdk** value from 8 to 13 in AndroidManifest.xml worked

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
```

My advise is start with value 18, if it works start reducing the value till it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed `parent`, and this worked:

```xml
<style name="DA.Dialog.Alert" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/DA.TextView</item>
</style>
```